# Got "Method Not Implemented" when access server resource

Tags: apache

For example:

web site: **www.a.com**

ip: **10.11.22.33**

There is a file named "test.txt" in the server.

When I use http://www.a.com/test.txt to access the file with browser, I get "501 Method Not Implemented".

But if I replace "www.a.com" with "10.11.22.33", it accesses the file successfully.

My Question: **How to resolve "Method Not Implemented"?**

**P.S** Server is Apache, and I tried to change browser, but still failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out finally...

It is because the "httpd.conf" file of Apache server loads a third party security module, which will intercept the "illegal" request like accessing ".txt" files.

It took me serval days to find out...Son of @&#^@#&@%*&^@!